# bash - test if files and folders exists in a for statement

Tags: bash, shell, file, for-loop, sh

I'm trying to print all files and folders of a directory.
The problem is that the print out of the `if` (`echo "$f out of if"`) is ok, but the code never execute the prints inside the `if` statements.

I'm sure that files and folders exists (printed out of if) and I checked the permissions.

dirPath is /tmp/testFolder.

```
for f in `ls $dirPath`; do
   echo "$f out of if"
   if [ -d $f ]; then
      echo "$f is a directory"
   fi
   if [ -f $f ]; then
      echo "$f is a file"
   fi
done
```

EDIT:
Thank you at all to answer!! I tryied this solution but I found the problem that "tmp/testFolder" (dirPath) is recognized as a folder too into the for-loop (and I need to find subfolder only).:

```
shopt -s globstar

for f in "$dirPath"/**; do
   echo "$f out of if"
   if [ -d $f ]; then
      echo "$f is a directory"
   fi
   if [ -f $f ]; then
      echo "$f is a file"
   fi
done
```

Comment: `for f in \`ls ...\`` [is broken](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: What's the output of that script?

Comment: The output is "namefile1 out of if", "namefile2 out of if", "namedir out of if"

Comment: *Never* use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) (there is a reason that is the #1 Pitfall) (hint - `ls` alone does not descend into subdirectores) Use `find` or enable `globstar` (`shopt -s globstar`) and use `for f in "$dirPath"/**`

Comment: Hi @DavidC.Rankin I like your elegant solution with globstar.. but is not working in my case (I don't know why). My bash version: GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Edit to @DavidC.Rankin not it run but it check into the for "tmp/testFolder" too.. and not only "tmp/testFolder/something"

Comment: Elena, I somehow have the feeling that we have a XY problem here. You are asking about X, but you want to solve Y. If this is just a fun script, I might be wrong. But if you ask for something like "copy all files, but ignore directories" or "keep all files, but delete all directories" or something like that, you might get totally different (and more effective) answers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that `$f` is a relative path. So `$f` is `test.file`, but you want to check `/tmp/testFolder/test.file`. The proper solution would be:

```
for f in "$dirPath"/*; do
   echo "$f out of if"
   if [ -d "$f" ]; then
      echo "$f is a directory"
   fi
   if [ -f "$f" ]; then
      echo "$f is a file"
   fi
done
```

Comment: Will not expand subdirectories of `$dirPath` and if `$dirPath` contains whitespace --- bad things will happen. Quote your variables `for f in "$dirPath"/*;` -- better `shopt -s globstar; for f in "$dirPath/**"; do`

Comment: Hello! @Ralf Thanks to answer! I tryied your solution but this is the output: (first part)/tmp/testFolder is a directory
/bin out
/bin is a directory
/boot out
/boot is a directory
/cdrom out
/cdrom is a directory
/dev out
/dev is a directory
/etc out
/etc is a directory
/home out
/home is a directory
/initrd.img out
/initrd.img is a file
/initrd.img.old out
/initrd.img.old is a file

Comment: @ElenaGuidi Is there a space at the end of `$dirPath`?

Comment: `/bin /boot /cdrom /dev /etc /home ...` are all off your `/` (root) directory -- something is going very wrong.

Comment: @melpomene no whitespaces, anyway I tryied to put the path like "tmp/testFolder" without variable to be sure

Comment: @ElenaGuidi Then you need to show your actual code.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Quotes added. Recursive was not in the actual question.

Comment: @Ralf, that was a bit unclear, I agree, and I'm still not entirely sure whether we want to further descend, but regardless, good job with the update, the quotes will save a lot of grief with the filename.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the `f` variable doesn't contain the full path to the file(s) in your target directory. So unless you give current directory, the tests for "directory" and "file" are always going to fail.

You could prefix with the `$dirPath` in your `if` statements (such as `if [ -d "$dirPath/$f" ]; then echo "$dirPath/$f is a directory"; fi`). Or better yet, use glob expansion in `for` loop instead which would give you full path to each file.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in "$dirPath"/*; do
   if [ -d "$f" ]; then
      echo "$f is a directory"
   elif [ -f "$f" ]; then
      echo "$f is a file"
   fi
done
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks to answer. I tryied with glob expansion and I have the problem that "he" check into the for "tmp/testFolder" too.. and not only "tmp/testFolder/something"

Comment: @ElenaGuidi I am not sure I understand your comment. Is `/tmp/testFolder` your `dirPath`? And what do you mean by "he" check?

Comment: I mean that in the in the for the code is not only checking the files and directories inside testFolder, is testing testFolder too.. look at the output:
tmp/testFolder/ out of if 
/tmp/testFolder/ is a directory
###I don't want the 2 lines before this comment ##
/tmp/testFolder/folder1 out of if
/tmp/testFolder/folder 2 is a directory

Comment: @ElenaGuidi That should happen. Are you sure you have the same code as in my answer? Can you try copy-pasting this code in a new script and test again?

Answer (score 1):

The code in `if` doesn't execute because there is no `namefile1` in the current directory, which is what your code is checking. That is, `$f` does not include `$dirPath` (the directory prefix) the way your code is written.

Better:

```
for f in "$dirPath"/*; do
    echo "$f out of if"
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then
        echo "$f is a directory"
    fi
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        echo "$f is a file"
    fi
done
```

See also the following list of bash pitfalls:

- [`for f in $(ls *.mp3)`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)
- [`[ -n $foo ]` or `[ -z $foo ]`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_-n_.24foo_.5D_or_.5B_-z_.24foo_.5D)

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that `f` is set to only the filename, not the entire path. That is, if /tmp/testFolder contains a file named example.txt, `f` will be set to just "example.txt", so `if [ -d $f ]; then` is checking for a file named "example.txt" in the current working directory, not in /tmp/testFolder. One option would be to use `if [ -d $dirPath/$f ]; then`, but there's a better way.

As a general rule, you [shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) because its output is ambiguous in several ways. To get a list of files in a particular directory, just use `dirpath/*` -- this gets a list of matching files without any of the ambiguity or parsing problems you'll have with `ls`. Bonus: it includes the specified path as part of the result (for example, `/tmp/testFolder/*` might give "/tmp/testFolder/example.txt").

Another suggestion: you should (almost) always put variable references in double-quotes, e.g. `"$f"` instead of just `$f`.

Fixing all of this gives:

```
for f in "$dirPath"/*; do    # Note that $dirPath should be quoted, but * cannot be
   echo "$f out of if"
   if [ -d "$f" ]; then
      echo "$f is a directory"
   fi
   if [ -f "$f" ]; then
      echo "$f is a file"
   fi
done
```

Note that the `echo` commands will also give the full path. If you don't want that, you can either use the `basename` command to get just the name portion, e.g. `f_name="$(basename "$f")"`, or (as @melpomene pointed out) use the expansion `"${f##*/}"` (which trims up to the last "/" in the variable):

```
for f in "$dirPath"/*; do
   f_name="${f##*/}"    # The quotes are not strictly needed in an assignment, but do no harm
   echo "$f_name out of if"
   if [ -d "$f" ]; then
      echo "$f_name is a directory"
   fi
   if [ -f "$f" ]; then
      echo "$f_name is a file"
   fi
done
```

Oh, and there's one possible downside to using a wildcard instead of `ls`: it'll return the raw wildcard if there are no matches. It doesn't matter in this case, but for places where it does you can either start the loop with `[ -e "$f" ] || continue` (i.e. skip the loop if there's nothing actually there), or if you're using bash (not just a generic shell) you can set the `nullglob` shell option (`shopt -s nullglob`).

One more recommendation: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common scripting mistakes, so I recommend running your scripts through it for suggestions.

Comment: `"${f##*/}"` saves spawning a `basename` process.

Comment: @melpomene There are a few cases (mainly when the path ends in "/") where that doesn't do the right thing, so I tend to use `basename`. But I don't think that can happen here, so I'll add that as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, you need only compare if `"$f"` is equal to `"$dataPath/"` to detect and avoid printing the `"$dataPath"` directory. (actually using `!=`) Continuing from your example (and incorporating all the comments about not using `for i in`ls anything`...), you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar   ## enable globstar

[ -z "$1" ] && {    ## validate at least 1 argument provided
    printf "error: insufficient input\nusage: %s path\n" "${0##*/}" >&2
    exit 1
}

datapath="$1"       ## set datapath

[ -d "$datapath" ] || { ## validate argument is a directory
    printf "error: invalid path - not a directory.\n" >&2
    exit 1;
}

## output absolute file/directory names
for f in "$datapath"/**; do     ## find files & subdirs below datapath
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then        ## am I a directory that isn't datapath
        [ "$f" != "$datapath/" ] && printf "directory: %s\n" "$f"
    elif [ -f "$f" ]; then      ## am I a file?
        printf "filename : %s\n" "$f"
    else                        ## am I neither a file or directory?
        printf "unknown  : %s\n" "$f"
    fi
done
```

Now if you only want the relative filenames below `"$dataPath"`, you simply need to trim `"dataPath/"` from the beginning of each filename using the *parameter expansion* `${parameter#[word]}` (where `[word]` expands to the pattern you want to match, e.g. `"$dataPath/"` here):

```
printf "\nwith relative path\n\n"
## output relative file/directory names
for f in "$datapath"/**; do
    relpath="${f#$datapath/}"   ## trim $datapath/ from f
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then
        [ -n "$relpath" ] && printf "directory: %s\n" "$relpath"
    elif [ -f "$f" ]; then
        printf "filename : %s\n" "$relpath"
    else
        printf "unknown  : %s\n" "$relpath"
    fi
done
```

Example including both above on the following directory structure:

**Example Directory**

```
$ tree ~/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr
/home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr
├── chkpass.c
├── dat
│   ├── pw
│   ├── users.bin
│   ├── users.bin.sav
│   └── users.txt
├── getpass.c
├── getpass.h
├── readuserdb.c
├── sha256d.c
├── sha256d.h
├── sha256dtst.c
├── sha256fread.c
├── sha256fread_timed.c
└── userdb.c
```

**Example Script Use/Output**

Including both absolute and relative paths, you would have:

```
$ bash ~/scr/utl/filelist.sh ~/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr
filename : /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr/chkpass.c
directory: /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr/dat
filename : /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr/dat/pw
filename : /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr/dat/users.bin
filename : /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr/dat/users.bin.sav
filename : /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr/dat/users.txt
filename : /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr/getpass.c
filename : /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr/getpass.h
filename : /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr/readuserdb.c
filename : /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr/sha256d.c
filename : /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr/sha256d.h
filename : /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr/sha256dtst.c
filename : /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr/sha256fread.c
filename : /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr/sha256fread_timed.c
filename : /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr/userdb.c

with relative path

filename : chkpass.c
directory: dat
filename : dat/pw
filename : dat/users.bin
filename : dat/users.bin.sav
filename : dat/users.txt
filename : getpass.c
filename : getpass.h
filename : readuserdb.c
filename : sha256d.c
filename : sha256d.h
filename : sha256dtst.c
filename : sha256fread.c
filename : sha256fread_timed.c
filename : userdb.c
```

(**note:** the output of `directory: /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/tst/sha2dcr/` is suppressed in both cases)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

(note: I use all lower-case variable names if you have an unexplained copy error...)